# Parse date and time form a csv file

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

I've some csv files with the following format:

```
330913;23;2;2013;0;0;6;8;7
330914;23;2;2013;0;5;25;8;7
330915;23;2;2013;0;10;11;8;7
330916;23;2;2013;0;15;30;8;7
330917;23;2;2013;0;20;17;8;7
330918;23;2;2013;0;25;4;8;7
```

I read them into a pandas DataFrame and need to specify a column (say) `'dt'` with the date and time. My best try so far is the following:

```
df = pd.read_csv( './cucu.csv', sep=';', \
    header=None, dtype='str' )
df[ 'dt' ] = pd.to_datetime(\
    df[3]+df[2]+df[1]+df[4]+df[5]+df[6], \
    format='%Y%m%d%H%M%S')
```

My question is, how do I do that without handling strings? I'm pretty sure I've done this in the past using something like:

```
df = pd.read_csv( './cucu.csv', sep=';', header=None, \
    parse_dates={'dt': [3,2,1,4,5,6]} )
```

but it's not working right now: I get a column  `dt` with strings like `2013 2 23 0 0 6`

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) method. Specifically, the `date_parser` kwarg is what you are looking for. It takes the resulting string created by the `parse_date` columns and processes it.

```
df = pd.read_csv('./cucu.csv', sep=';', header=None, parse_dates={'dt': [3,2,1,4,5,6]}, date_parser=lambda dts: pd.to_datetime(dts, format='%Y %m %d %H %M %S'))
```

Comment: Yup, that was it, thanks! A question: Is there any reason to put double brackets in `[[3,2,1,4,5,6]]`? Seems to work with single as well...

Comment: Hmmm single list throws an error for me in this code.

Comment: @Luis According to the docs "list of ints or names. e.g. If [1, 2, 3] -> try parsing columns 1, 2, 3 each as a separate date column." and "list of lists. e.g. If [[1, 3]] -> combine columns 1 and 3 and parse as
a single date column."

Comment: @Luis So with a single list, the values in each of those columns are passed to the `date_parser` function.

Comment: Sorry, my bad, I used `parse_dates={'dt': [3,2,1,4,5,6]}`. `parse_dates=[3,2,1,4,5,6]` throws an error here too.

Comment: That's probably better since you have a names column... Updated answer!